# device tree overlay phandle

Tags: linux-kernel, device-tree

I'm working on a Cyclone V SOC FPGA from Altera with a double Cortex-A9 processor. The embedded system (linux-socfpga 4.16) is created with Buildroot-2018.05.

I use a "top" device tree at boot time for processor component and a device-tree overlay to configure the FPGA part of the component and load the associated drivers. The overlay will be attach to the `base_fpga_region` of the top DT.

---

## top device tree

```
/dts-v1/;

/ {
    model = "MY_PROJECT";   /* appended from boardinfo */
    compatible = "altr,socfpga-cyclone5", "altr,socfpga";   /* appended from boardinfo */
    #address-cells = <1>;
    #size-cells = <1>;

    cpus {
        [...]
    }; //end cpus

    memory {
        device_type = "memory";
        reg = <0xffff0000 0x00010000>,
            <0x00000000 0x80000000>;
    }; //end memory

    reserved-memory {
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <1>;
        ranges;

        mem_dma_reserved {
            compatible = "shared-dma-pool";
            no-map;
            reg = <0x78000000 0x8000000>;
        };
    };

    soc: soc {
        device_type = "soc";
        ranges;
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <1>;
        compatible = "altr,avalon", "simple-bus";
        bus-frequency = <0>;

        fpgabridge1: fpgabridge@1 {
            compatible = "altr,socfpga-lwhps2fpga-bridge";
            resets = <&hps_rstmgr 97>;  /* appended from boardinfo */
            clocks = <&l4_main_clk>;    /* appended from boardinfo */           
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <1>;
            ranges;
            bridge-enable = <1>;

            label = "lwhps2fpga";
            reset-names = "lwhps2fpga";
            reg = <0xff200000 0x200000>;
            reg-names = "axi_h2f_lw";
        }; //end fpgabridge@1 (fpgabridge1)

        base_fpga_region: base_fpga_region  {
            compatible = "fpga-region";
            #address-cells = <0x2>;
            #size-cells = <0x1>;
            fpga-mgr = <&hps_fpgamgr>;
            fpga-bridges = <&fpgabridge1>;          
            ranges = <0x0 0x0 0xff200000 0x200000>;
        }; //end base_fpga_region (base_fpga_region)

etc......
```

## Device tree overlay

```
/dts-v1/ /plugin/; 

/{ 
    fragment@0 { 
        target-path = "/soc/base_fpga_region"; 
        #address-cells = <2>; 
        #size-cells = <1>; 
        __overlay__ { 
            #address-cells = <2>; 
            #size-cells = <1>; 

            firmware-name = "my_project.rbf";

            my_dma_0: dma@0x000000000 {
                compatible = "my_company,my_dma-0.1";
                reg = <0x00000000 0x0000000 0x00000014>;
                memory-region = <&mem_dma_reserved>;
            }; //end dma@0x000000000 (my_dma_0)      
        }; 
    }; 
};
```

---

my problem is to link the `mem_dma_reserved` from the top DT to the `memory-region` in the overlay.

I assume that while converting dts to dtbo with the -@ option, the overlay shall get the phandle for `mem_dma_reserved` with the `__fixups__` option. I've created the dtbo file and converted it again in dts to see what is done during the compilation :

```
dtc -@ -I dts -O dtb -o overlay.dtbo overlay.dts
dtc -I dtb -O dts -o overlay_recovery.dts overlay.dtbo
```

---

## device tree overlay regenerated

```
/dts-v1/;    
/ {

    fragment@0 {
        target-path = "/soc/base_fpga_region";
        #address-cells = <0x2>;
        #size-cells = <0x1>;

        __overlay__ {
            #address-cells = <0x2>;
            #size-cells = <0x1>;
            firmware-name = "my_project.rbf";

            dma@0x000000000 {
                compatible = "my_company,my_dma-0.1";
                reg = <0x0 0x0 0x14>;
                memory-region = <0xffffffff>;  // phandle converted to 0xffffffff, cannot resolve unless the __fixup__ function does it.
                linux,phandle = <0x2>;
                phandle = <0x2>;
            };
        };
    };

    __symbols__ {
        my_dma_0 = "/fragment@0/__overlay__/dma@0x000000000";
    };

    __fixups__ {
        mem_dma_reserved = "/fragment@0/__overlay__/dma@0x000000000:memory-region:0";
    };
};
```

---

We can see that the phandle for the memory-region is 0xFFFFFFFF because the overlay doesn't know about the <&mem_dma_reserved> node. the fixup part shall be able to get back the phandle at loading time, but it isn't working and I get this error :

> [   27.434730] OF: resolver: of_resolve_phandles: no symbols in root of device tree.
>   [   27.440401] OF: resolver: overlay phandle fixup failed: -22
>   [   27.445993] create_overlay: Failed to resolve tree

I have made the same regeneration from dtb to dts on the top DT. I have seen that the phandle of the reserved memory is actually 0x6. I have written <0x6> instead of <&mem_dma_reserved> in the device tree overlay and with this configuration, everything loads !

How can I make the overlay find the <&mem_dma_reserved> automatically without doing it by hand ?

### EDIT

As pointed by **ikwzm** I have added in the top device tree the following lines :

```
reserved-memory {
    #address-cells = <1>;
    #size-cells = <1>;
    ranges;

    mem_dma_reserved: mem_dma_reserved { // add a label
        compatible = "shared-dma-pool";
        no-map;
        reg = <0x78000000 0x8000000>;
    };
};    

[...]    

// add the whole symbol block
__symbols__ { 
    mem_dma_reserved = "/reserved-memory/mem_dma_reserved ";
};
```

The errors are now gone, but :

I was expecting the driver for my_dma to be loaded during the operation.

I checked that the device tree overlay is well taken into account with :

> **ls /sys/firmware/devicetree/base/soc/base_fpga_region/**
>     my_dma_0
>     other_stuff
>
> **cat /sys/firmware/devicetree/base/soc/base_fpga_region/my_dma_0/memory-region**
>    //nothing//

The memory region doesn't seem to be attached.

What I have missed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When making the top dtb, did you attach the option --symbol (or -@) to the dtc command?

Add a label (symbol) to mem_dma_reserved as follows.

```
reserved-memory {
    #address-cells = <1>;
    #size-cells = <1>;
    ranges;

    mem_dma_reserved: mem_dma_reserved {
        compatible = "shared-dma-pool";
        no-map;
        reg = <0x78000000 0x8000000>;
    };
};
```

When dtb is created with the --symbol option dtc command, `__symbols__{...};` is added as follows, and `mem_dma_reserved = "/reserved-memory/ mem_dma_reserved";` should be found in it.

```
__symbols__ {
    :
    :
    :
    mem_dma_reserved = "/reserved-memory/mem_dma_reserved";
    usb_phy0 = "/phy0";
};
```

Comment: I tried this solution but the kernel get stuck at boot time at "Starting kernel ..." I assume my device tree has something wrong when enabling this option

Comment: Ok, it was fixup lines which were preveting the kernel from booting. I have added the __symbols__ by hand in the dts file and compile without the option -@

Comment: I change my `dtc` version and now the device tree overlay is well mounted with your solution. The only issue is that my driver is not probing now. Only the init function is called... Well, it will need another question if I cannot solve it by myself