# Creating a Device-Tree for the hardware on a PCI device

Tags: linux-device-driver, fpga, device-tree

I'm in the process of writing a Linux device-driver for some custom hardware controlled via a PCIe card. The PCIe card contains an FPGA implementing SPI and I2C bus masters along with other custom firmware. There are already platform-bus device-drivers in the kernel for a lot of the hardware and I'd like to avoid duplicating that work.

Is there any way of creating a Device-Tree to describe the hardware on the 
card?

My thinking was that as the card is discovered and probed, it would map the BARS, register the device-tree and have the existing drivers pick-up the mapped address regions and provide interfaces to the hardware.

Comment: Consider editing your title to make your question clearer.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50948932/device-tree-overlay-phandle

Answer (score 2):

Here is a snippet of a PCI device (VID,PID: 1234,5678) present on pci0 of an ARM board:

```dts
&pci0 {
    pci0,0 {
        #address-cells = <3>;
        #size-cells = <2>;
        reg = <0 0 0 0 0>;
        device_type = "pci";
        ranges = <0x82000000 0x0 0x40000000 0x82000000 0x0 0x40000000 0 0x40000000>;

        fpga@0 {
            compatible = "pci1234,5678";

            reg = <0x0000 0 0 0 0>;
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <1>;
            ranges = <0 0x82000000 0x0 0x48000000 0x2000000>;

            i2c@100400 {
                compatible = "snps,designware-i2c";
                reg = <0x100400 0x100>;
                #address-cells = <1>;
                #size-cells = <0>;
                interrupts = <8>;
                i2c-sda-hold-time-ns = <300>;
                clock-frequency = <100000>;
            };

            spi@101000 {
                compatible = "snps,dw-apb-ssi";
                #address-cells = <1>;
                #size-cells = <0>;
                reg = <0x101000 0x1000>, <0x3c 0x18>;
                interrupts = <10>;

                flash@0 {
                    compatible = "mx25l25635e", "jedec,spi-nor";
                    spi-max-frequency = <20840000>;
                    reg = <0>;
                };
            };
        };
    };
};
```

This was working on a kernel v4.19 and may have been broken since. The main issue is that the PCI translation of device tree adresses is not quite right and so has to be done using the ranges property which ends up making the DT snippet device specific.

Comment: Did you register driver for compatible = "pci1234,5678" as pci_device or platform_device?
I have been trying to do similar thing using mfd driver  and I have registered pci_driver with static struct pci_driver cco_qdma_driver = {
    .driver = {
        .name = "cco-qdma-mfd",
        .of_match_table = cco_cassino_of_ids,
    }, 
...
};
but pci_dev->of_node is NULL?

Comment: @ozimki, I see that you commented on here even before I suggested your Q to be dup of this one. The driver should be PCI driver, then you split it into more device drivers if needed, there are plenty of drivers under MFD subsystem that are PCI drivers.

Comment: @0andriy I think the added part of the question was similar to this one but the initial NULL node was not. I thought that the node should always be populated when there was a matching compatible" in the DT tree... my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Device tree bindings are redundant or not necessary for USB and PCI devices as they are probed. they send info as part of probing process.

But yes SPI and I2C will be needed to add in DTS (Device Tree Source) file.

Information provided is insufficient to provide answer for code duplication.

Device Tree is used to define board description. which avoid board description in kernel.

Comment: This is not an answer.